# how to handle REST API error centrally with Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to build an central error handling using Camel.

I want that all my routes exposing REST endpoints would have transparent error handling translating Exceptions into HTTP error codes in one piece of code.

Currently I achieve this with an Abstract RouteBuilder defining an onException route in its Contructor. When I inherit it in a concrete RouteBuilder it works fine.
However this is not transparent since I have to know that I have to inherit from the abstract class to have it working.

**Is there any mechanism in Camel similar to Jersey ExceptionMapper?**

What I need is a place in the Camel framework where I can configure the error handling without the need to ensure that any team member has to remember to inherit the abstract error handling class.

*what I currently have*

```
public abstract class ErrorHandlerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    public ErrorHandlerRoute () {
        super();

        onException().handled(true)
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
                //handle exceptions here
                exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                exchange.getOut().setFault(false);
            });
    }
}

public class MyBusinessRoute extends ErrorHandlerRoute {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        //OK, I know that my errors will be handled

        rest()
        .get("/{param}")
        to("http4://backend");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look into [ErrorHandler](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/error-handler.adoc)s already?

Comment: @RomanVottner yes I did but gave up since I could not return a custom answer to the client using the defaultErrorHandler. It looks like it always returns the raw stack trace as a response body whatever I hook as custom processing